# how to make a batch file that only writes down image names from a certain size

Tags: batch-file

I need to have the names of images that are above a certain file size, so i can replace them with smaller sized images. I already used the following code to retrieve all of the names but now I only want the names of large images.

```
(FOR %%f IN (*.*)DO @ECHO %%f; )> myfiles.txt
```

Comment: The question is, what do you mean by "size": are you talking about the file size (in bytes), or are you talking about the dimensions of the image (width and height in pixels)?

Comment: I'm talking about the file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@(
 FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
  IF %%~zf GTR 100000 (
    (ECHO(%%f;)
  )
 ) 
)> myfiles.txt
```

mind that `%%~zf` will expand the size in bites.

Comment: Is there also a way to loop this through different folders and subfolders?

Comment: @Mylan - yes - use `FOR /r %%f IN (*.*) DO  ..` though in this way the whole file path will be printed in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Example for files >=1MB:

```
(FOR %%f IN (*.*)DO @IF %%~tf GTE 1048576 ECHO %%f; )> myfiles.txt
```